# Transaction from one Fragment to another with beginTransaction()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm pretending to switch from one Fragment to another and get a saved Bundle configuration between them:

*Fragment A (named SpotSelection)*

```
    // Communication
    interface OnMessageSendListener {
        public fun onMessageSend(id: Int, currentFragment: Fragment)
    }

    var messageSendListener: OnMessageSendListener? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        val activity: Activity = context as Activity

        try {
            messageSendListener = activity as OnMessageSendListener
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            throw ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onMessageSendListener...")
        }
    }

[...]

// This is a method of a setOnClickListener button, to switch from the fragment "SpotSelection" to the fragment "Spots" when I press the button

private fun entrarColeccion(id: Int) {
        Log.d("selection", "Entrando en onMessageSend(" + id + ")")
        getVisibleFragment()?.let { messageSendListener?.onMessageSend(id, it) }
        // I cannot do this because I would miss the Bundle ;( it would be so easy...
        //findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_spotSelection_to_spots)
    }

    fun getVisibleFragment(): Fragment? {
        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager
        val fragments: List<Fragment> = fragmentManager.getFragments()
        if (fragments != null) {
            for (fragment in fragments) {
                if (fragment != null && fragment.isVisible) return fragment
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

*MainActivity*

```
    // SpotSelection Communication
    override fun onMessageSend(id: Int, currentFragment: Fragment) {
        Log.d("selection", "Dentro de onMessageSend(" + id + ")")

        // The Fragment where I want to go
        val spotsFragment: Spots = Spots()

        val bundle: Bundle = bundleOf(Pair("coleccionID", id))
        Log.d("selection", "Guardando bundle: (coleccionID, " + id + ")")

        spotsFragment.setArguments(bundle)

        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .hide(currentFragment)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, spotsFragment)
            .show(spotsFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
    }
```

It does the following (by my observations of the debbuger): hides the actual fragment (SpotSelection), start the onCreateView of the Spots fragment (where I want to go), but doesn't display its UI. How do I display the UI of Spots? I feel like I'm so close...

Answer (score 0):

using replace may cause problem some times use this maybe help you:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager  = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

    if(fragment == null){
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .hide(currentFragment)
        .add(R.id.fragment_container, spotsFragment)
        .show(spotsFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
    }else{
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .hide(currentFragment)
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, spotsFragment)
        .show(spotsFragment)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit()
    }
```